# Dockerfile production/build/debug/test environment

Tags: docker, development-environment, production-environment, dockerfile, test-environments

Imagine you have your web application and some workflow executors:

- http-server (serving pre-build asset files) - production
- builder (compiling/bundling js/css/html from sources) - deployment/development
- debugger/builder (building from sources on the fly, add js source maps) - development
- selenium (running tests) - integration testing

How can we construct layered images to get those workflow executors working the most effectively? By effectively I mean "fastest to run and least to write".

Comment: Well, there's also unit testing, but that's probably another one.

Comment: That is not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169098/dockerfile-and-dev-test-prod-environment
It's slightly different. This is  a more general one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be straightforward: just create 4 `Dockerfile`s one depending on another.

You can add a volume to share build from sources part. The question is whether you want result assets to be included in the image or build it from sources each time.

Create 4 folders to have `Dockerfile` in each.

**Production**

`production/Dockefile`:

```
FROM  # put server here
COPY  # put config here
# some other option
# volume sharing?
```

**Build**

`build/Dockerfile`:

```
# install dependencies
ADD # add sources here
RUN # some building script
```

**Debug**

`debug/Dockefile`:

```
# ideally, configure production or build image
```

**Test**

`test/Dockefile`:

```
FROM # import production
# install test dependencies
RUN # test runner
```

There are also several options.
1. Use .gitignore with negative pattern (or ADD?)

```
*
!directory-i-want-to-add
!another-directory-i-want-to-add
```

Plus use docker command specifying dockerfiles and context:

```
docker build -t my/debug-image -f docker-debug .
docker build -t my/serve-image -f docker-serve .
docker build -t my/build-image -f docker-build .
docker build -t my/test-image -f docker-test .
```

You could also use different gitignore files.

2. Mount volumes
   Skip sending context at all, just use mounting  volumes during run time (using `-v host-dir:/docker-dir`).

So you'd have to:

```
docker build -t my/build-image -f docker-build . # build `build` image (devtools like gulp, grunt, bundle, npm, etc)
docker run -v output:/output my/build-image build-command # copies files to output dir
docker build -t my/serve-image -f docker-serve . # build production from output dir
docker run my/serve-image # production-like serving from included or mounted dir
docker build -t my/serve-image -f docker-debug . # build debug from output dir
docker run my/serve-image # debug-like serving (uses build-image with some watch magic)
```

Comment: This might not work for all test runners/debuggers/builders, but that's the ideal we should strive for. IMHO.